# Android - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, jar, gradle

I've insert to my app/libs a [jar files](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations).

[image]

the project is rebuild well, but when I try to run it I get an error.
I try to remove each one and rebuild, but each one throw this exception.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Android_Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\com.haarman.listviewanimations-2.6.0-87a736264468420dc84a2b039abd98cb30236f3e.jar C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\library-2.4.0-20d32ecd21e3da938f108347439a0d353ef8793e.jar C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\nineoldandroids-2.4.0-71a8249321cc0bae33765bcea724852248245ce6.jar C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-ff079e6ae11e9ea90a76291957a9366f1a1f17f8.jar
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "egabay.journey"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:library:2.6.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Do i need to modify build.gradle?

Comment: do you know where support-v4-19.1.0*.jar is coming from? Did you download it from somewhere?

Comment: I've tried to remark this line and still, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved it.
In my trying to understand I delete both jar files from the lib folder and then undo (Ctr+shift+z), this cause the files to return to my project with **SIZE 0** ! I don't know why.

more I've updated my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.haarman.listviewanimations-2.6.0.jar')
}
```

Thanks for the help.